# Can people on Facebook see photos in albums hidden from them on my mutual friend's timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags, facebook-privacy

I have three questions:

1. If I post something on my timeline that I specifically hide from person X, but in that post I have tagged persons Y and Z, both of whom are friends of mine AND friends of X, what happens? The post is now on the timelines of Y and Z, because I tagged them in it. X cannot see it on my timeline, because I opted to hide the post from X; but X see Y and Z’s timeline since they are friends as well. Can X see this particular post on Y and Z’s wall, or, since I’m the one who originated the post, and elected to hide it from X, is it hidden from X even on Y and Z’s wall?
2. If I choose in *Privacy Settings* that person X can’t see the photos I’am tagged in, can X see that photo that our mutual friend Y has tagged my in?
3. If I choose in *Privacy settings* that person X can’t see the photos I’am tagged in or the ones I upload, can X see the photo I upload and tag myself, on our mutual friend Y’s timeline or on X’s newsfeeds from Y?

Answer (score 3):

Good question. Let me explain the answer one by one.

1. If you are the one uploading that photo, your privacy settings will apply to the post. If you've set the `friends of friends` settings, all the friends of your friends can see the photo, if you tag your friends in it. The exception is if you've explicitly excluded a person or list from the post. In that case they won't be able to see it, except if your friends reshare the photo.
2. If your friends is the one who uploaded the picture, his/her privacy settings will apply. The person you've blocked can see the photo, but can't see your tag in it.
3. Same as answer 1. He can't see unless the post is shared by one of your friends.

Comment: Thank you so much! it was a relief! So basically, the setting of the one who posts it will be applied and I can not hide a photo or post from a mutual friend X, if our mutual friend Y uploads it or tags me in. right?

Comment: yep, you can though approve or disapprove your tag on other people's photos. You just need to have that settings in privacy settings.